# Play encrypted video with AVPlayer

Tags: objective-c, encryption, avplayer

I'm implementing an application that contains video player. For some reasons video files are encrypted with AES, and size of these files can be rather big to avoid loading it to RAM as one piece. I'm looking for some way to play it with AVPlayer.

Tried:

1) Custom NSURLProtocol as suggested here http://aptogo.co.uk/2010/07/protecting-resources/
Didn't work, I suggest that AVPlayer uses it's own and mine does not get called.

2) Use AVAsset to chop video in small chunks and then feed them to AVPlayer - failed because there's no API in AVPlayer for that.

Any workaround would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If you have encrypted files, we should **at least** know the format etc. Have you looked into creating a proxy that does the decryption? What are your expectations/use cases (seeking etc.)?

Comment: I can't understand exactly, what did you mean. You offer to create proxy, but for what? In my mind there is following algorithm:
1. Catch encrypted data, that AVPlayer tries to load by url.
2. Decrypt it.
3. Put decrypted data in AVPlayer.

Quite possible that it is wrong, because AVPlayer hasn't any Data Provider. But I don't know other way.

Comment: You could create a web proxy that connects to the actual content and aim an URL to a local service that decrypts the data. In this way you can decouple the encryption/decryption and playing the video.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm in the same situation, except with audio files... I've implemented a custom NSURLProtocol class, but it never gets called.

Comment: I was going through 'Real-time Video Processing Using AVPlayerItemVideoOutput', maybe could help https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVBasicVideoOutput/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 options:

1. If targeting iOS 7 and newer the check out `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`. It allows you to do what you would with a custom `NSURLProtocol` but specifically for `AVPlayer`.
2. Emulate an HTTP server with support for the Range header and point the `AVURLAsset` to localhost.

I implemented #2 before and can provide more info if needed.

Comment: Could you give more details on 2. ?

Comment: I've the same problem. Would you mind opening your solution, please.

Comment: @JerneyStrasner Could you provide more info about #2. I have been trying to implement this using `CocoaHTTPServer` for ages but my videos I try to play back mess up after 3 seconds of playback.

Comment: Jernej, could you provide more details on 1.

Comment: Any actual samples available?

Answer (score 3):

I just downloaded the Apple sample project https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc1791/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html and it seems to do exactly what you want.

The delegate catch each `AVURLAsset`'s `AVAssetResourceLoader` calls and makes up a brand new `.m3a8` file with a custom decryption key in it.
Then it feeds the player with all `.ts` file URLs in the `m3a8`.

The project is a good overview of what it is possible to do with HLS feeds.