# AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate protocol on iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, avplayer

I have managed to get `AVPlayer` working with `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` to play m4a file on `iOS 7` but I cannot do it on `iOS 6`.

The

```
- (BOOL)resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader
shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest
```

delegate method is getting called with following request:

```
2014-05-12 15:14:58.798 AVPlayer-Delegate[661:1103] Requested data: {
    Range = "bytes=0-1";
    "X-Playback-Session-Id" = "5B64BE4E-442A-4A37-9263-04D22CDBCB28";
}
```

I am returning the two first bytes as requested but the delegate method is never called again. I was trying to provide various headers in the response object I am passing but it didn't help.

This is my implementation:

```
- (BOOL)resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader

shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest

{

    NSLog(@"Requested data: %@",

          loadingRequest.request.allHTTPHeaderFields);

    NSDictionary *headers = @{@"Content-Type": @"audio/x-m4a",

                              @"Accept-Ranges" : @"bytes",

                              @"Content-Length" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 2],

                              @"Content-Range" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bytes 0-1/%d", self.fileData.length],

                              @"X-Playback-Session-Id" : loadingRequest.request.allHTTPHeaderFields[@"X-Playback-Session-Id"],

                              @"ETag" : @"TAG"};

    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:loadingRequest.request.URL statusCode:206 HTTPVersion:@"HTTP/1.1" headerFields:headers];

    //NSURLResponse *response = [[NSURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:loadingRequest.request.URL MIMEType:@"audio/m4a" expectedContentLength:self.fileData.length textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"];



    NSData *requestedData = [self.fileData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];

    [loadingRequest finishLoadingWithResponse:response data:requestedData redirect:nil];



    return YES;

}
```

I would really appreciate any help with it.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm seeing the same behavior (only first two bytes requested) on an iOS 7 device.  There are no requests after the initial request for the first two bytes.

Answer (score 1):

AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate works differently on IOS 6 and IOS 7. See [What's New in IOS 7.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html)

> The AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate protocol now supports loading of
>   arbitrary ranges of bytes from a media resource.

The standard pre-IOS7 workaround is to use a local HTTP server. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/21225985

Comment: So what's the purpose of AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate protocol on iOS 6 if it cannot be used for loading arbitrary ranges of bytes? Are there any other possible usage scenarios? Thanks.